# Js показывает непонятную ошибку

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".btnY-sec")[0].onclick = function() {
  newLineSec()
};

function newLineSec() {
  console.log("asd")
}
```

```html
<button class='btnY-sec'><i class='fa fa-check-circle' aria-hidden='true' style = 'color:#149A00;'></i></button>
```

> script.js:182 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined

тут почему то работает

все сработало, ошибка была у меня в html-е откуда и я вырезал button

//Правильный ответ ---> Есть вероятность, что скрипт у вас запускается раньше, чем прогружается документ. Соответственно в querySelectorAll(".btnY-sec")[0] будет null.

Comment: какую ошибку показывает?

Comment: Есть вероятность, что скрипт у вас запускается раньше, чем прогружается документ. Соответственно в `querySelectorAll(".btnY-sec")[0]` будет `null`.

Comment: @Frog так и было) благодарю)